# How to embolden frame ticks?

Tags: plotting, labeling, ticks, frame

For the following sample plot, how can I make the `FrameTicks` appear bold in black color?

[image].

Following is the sample code:

```
Show[
 Plot[
  {Sin[x], x}
  , {x, 0, π}
  , Epilog -> {
    Black, AbsolutePointSize[5]
    , Point[{π/8, Sin[π/8]}]
    }
  , Frame -> True
  , FrameStyle -> Directive[Black]
  , FrameTicks -> {
    {{-1, -0.5, 0, -0, 0.5, 1}, None}
    , {{0.0, π/4, π/2, π, 3 π/4, 2 π}, None}
    }
  , Axes -> {False, False}
  , PlotLegends -> Placed[
    LineLegend[{"Sin", "x"}
     , LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}
     , LegendMarkerSize -> 15]
    , {0.2, 0.2}
    ]
  ]
 , PlotRange -> {{0.0, π}, {-1, 1}}
 , AxesLabel -> {x, "E"}
 , LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}
 ]
```

For example, how would I mimic ticks in the following plot?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TicksStyle` or `FrameTicksStyle` as necessary:

```
Plot[
  {Sin[x], x}, {x, 0, \[Pi]}, 
  ...all your other options...
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[.02]]]
```

Oh, you were more concerned about the tick label. These options handle the text styles as well:

```
FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Bold, 24, Red, Thickness[.02]]
```

(I just made up directives to make the appearance changes very obvious. You'd choose your own directives.)