# LaTeX typeset for the frame ticks

Tags: plotting, ticks, latex, frame, matex

Following [this site](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html), I inserted a LaTeX type set for the frame ticks. Following is the sample code.

```
Plot[
  Sin[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black],
  FrameTicks -> 
    {
     {{-1, -0.5, 0, -0, 0.5, 1}, None}, 
     {With[{ticks = Pi/4 Range[0, 4]}, Thread[{ticks, MaTeX[ticks, "DisplayStyle" -> False]}]], None}
    }, 
  Axes -> {False, False}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.0, \[Pi]}, {-1, 1}},
  AxesLabel -> {x, "E"}, LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}
]
```

Below is the obtained plot:[image]

How to change the size of the x-axis frame tick labels and make them bold?

Comment: Why do you need LaTex for this? Just do ```FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Range[0, Pi, Pi/4], None}}```

Comment: @rhomboidRhipper OP had [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285352/how-to-bold-frame-ticks) before on doing this using Mathematica without Latex. He must wanted now to do the same using Latex in Mathematica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to change the size of the x-axis frame tick labels and make them
> bold?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Code

```
<< MaTeX`
myNiceBigTicks = 
  With[{ticks = Pi/4 Range[0, 4]}, 
   {#, MaTeX["\\boldsymbol{" <> ToString@TeXForm[#] <> "}", 
       "DisplayStyle" -> False, Magnification -> 2]} & /@ ticks];

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black],
 FrameTicks -> 
   {
     {{-1, -0.5, 0, -0, 0.5, 1}, None}, 
     {myNiceBigTicks, None}
   },
 Axes -> {False, False}, PlotRange -> {{0.0, Pi}, {-1, 1}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, "E"}, LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}
]
```

> Is it also possible to bold the y-axis numbers together with x- axis?

The same thing can be done:

```
<< MaTeX`
myX = With[{ticks = 
     Pi/4 Range[0, 4]}, {#, 
      MaTeX["\\boldsymbol{" <> ToString@TeXForm[#] <> "}", 
       "DisplayStyle" -> False, Magnification -> 1.5]} & /@ ticks];
myY = With[{ticks = 
     Range[-1, 1, 1/2]}, {#, 
      MaTeX["\\boldsymbol{" <> ToString@TeXForm[#] <> "}", 
       "DisplayStyle" -> False, Magnification -> 1.5]} & /@ ticks];

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black], GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotStyle -> Red,
 FrameTicks -> {{myY, None}, {myX, None}}, Axes -> {False, False}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.0, Pi}, {-1, 1}}, AxesLabel -> {x, "E"}, 
 LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice, this is not automated and need to manually give the range each time.  Also Mathematica writes  `1.` as `1` for labels and `1/2` as `0.5`. If you want the same you can add more code to do this. This is left as an exercise. The problem is that using `Range[-1,1,.5]` will produce `{-1., -0.5, 0., 0.5, 1.}` and not `{-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1}` like mathematica does. So just need special formatting added, that is why I used `Range[-1, 1, 1/2]` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Is it also possible to bold the y-axis numbers together with x- axis?

Comment: @Rakesh  fyi, updated.

Comment: For the y-axis, I want to use Mathematica font. If I use  "FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Bold, 9, Black, Thickness[.003]]", it doesn't look uniform in color for both the x-axis and y-axis. Is there a way, to make y-axis numbers bold with mathematical font?

Comment: As mentioned above, if I use "FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Bold, 9, Black, Thickness[.003]]", some tick lines become thick and some become slightly thicker.

Comment: @Rakesh it is not good idea to use Latex for one axis and Mathematica for another. They will not look same. MaTeX uses pdflatex to compile, and that uses the Computer Modern typeface family by default. You have to decide, either use Latex for ticks labels on everything, or use Mathematica's own typesetting. I think you asked in another question about using Mathematica for this. Anyway, I do not think I can help more I am afraid on this. good luck.